# Focus on last symbol in input, but not in visible zone

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To see the problem you need to type "ATW" in input.

The problem is, when I press Enter and change input value => the last symbol of pasted string is not in visible zone of input, until I continue typing.

Pasted string in input is "All The Web, Around The Web, All The Way, At The Weekend".

Now I see https://ibb.co/C5KVcGk, but I expected https://ibb.co/6Jd3rrQ

How to solve it?

I create sandbox with this code to try in.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exadEy?editors=1010

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
    changeValue: ''
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
      changeValue: e.target.value === 'ATW' 
        ? 'All The Web, Around The Web, All The Way, At The Weekend'
        : ''
    });
  }

  handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (this.state.changeValue) {

        return this.setState({
          value: this.state.value.replace(
              this.state.value,
              this.state.changeValue
            ),
          changeValue: ''
        })   
      }

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p></p>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Type ATW"
          ref={input => this.messageInput = input}
          value={this.state.value}
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />

        {this.state.changeValue && 
          <span>Press Enter to confirm changes: "{this.state.changeValue}"</span>
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Input />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: I don't get it ... What do you mean by `the last symbol is not in visible zone` ? ... I can see the last `d` of `Weekend` at the end of the input ...

Comment: After you click Enter you see https://ibb.co/C5KVcGk, but should this https://ibb.co/6Jd3rrQ

Comment: I can't understand what is your problem

Comment: One more time. If I paste long string like "start of this long long long long string and this is the end". 
In input I should see "...is the end"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hack is to use

```
this.messageInput.blur();
this.messageInput.focus();
```

in the handleKeyDown in setState callback function.

This works, but maybe someone has better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must have a look at [THIS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/move-cursor-to-end-of-input/) function

The fact is the the cursor is reset to the initial position in the input ... You have to make it to th end

Comment: this function did not help